# ClientAbortException with Spring Boot on downloading large files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, tomcat

Sometimes when downloading a large file (~1GB) from my Spring Boot application a ClientAbortException occurs. I am using "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.4.RELEASE" from maven central.

**reproducability**
I could only reproduce it in Google Chrome. In Edge (although based on chrome) it works all the time). Id only does fail occasionally. I also tried to download multiple files at the same time to increase the download time and provoke a timeout, but does not guarantee a failure. sometimes a file works, sometimes not. But most of the time the first download after restarting the server application fails (if done in chrome)

**Stacktrace**

> org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
> at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:166)
> at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:137)
> at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:129)
> at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45)
> at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:280)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:138)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:152)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1253)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:764)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:584)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:528)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:546)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193)
> at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339)
> ... 57 more

**My Setup**
The way my servers are set up is the following:
VM1 has a nginx running and proxies the call to VM2 with the application.
the application runs in a docker container with `openjdk:11-jre` as base image

*nginx config for the proxy part*

```
proxy_pass      http://10.0.0.3:2080/;
proxy_read_timeout 1d;
```

Before implementing it with spring boot, the server was written with vertx. The vertx implementation did not have those issues. The vertx implementation did not set the `content-length` header.

**Code**

```
@GetMapping("{fileId:.+}")
fun getFile(@PathVariable fileId: String): ResponseEntity<PathResource> {
    var asMap = fileIdCache.asMap()
    if (!asMap.containsValue(fileId)) {
        FileLoader().getAllFiles()
                .map { FileLoader.FILEPATH.relativize(it).joinToString("/", transform = java.nio.file.Path::toString) }
                .forEach { fileIdCache[it] }
        asMap = fileIdCache.asMap()
    }
    val filename = asMap.toList()
                           .filter { it.second == fileId }
                           .map { it.first }
                           .firstOrNull() ?: throw NotFoundException(fileId)
    val path = FileLoader.FILEPATH.resolve(filename)
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        throw NotFoundException(fileId)
    }
    info("requested File: $path")

    val encoded = URLEncoder.encode(path.fileName.toString(), Charsets.UTF_8).replace("+", "%20")
    val probeContentType = Files.probeContentType(path)
    info("probed content: $probeContentType")
    val type = probeContentType?.let(MediaType::valueOf) ?: MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM

    val resource = PathResource(path)
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=$encoded")
            .contentType(type)
            .body(resource)
}
```

**Response headers**

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=2592000
content-disposition: attachment;filename=video.mkv
content-length: 1084320986
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Sat, 10 Oct 2020 16:28:26 GMT
expires: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 16:28:26 GMT
referrer-policy: origin
server: nginx
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Origin
vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

Old response headers from vertx implementation

```
cache-control: max-age=2592000
content-disposition: attachment;filename="video.mkv"
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Sat, 10 Oct 2020 17:45:51 GMT
expires: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 17:45:51 GMT
referrer-policy: origin
server: nginx
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

I found some solutions mentioning to add the content-length header (which is there and correct) or add the `proxy_read_timeout` in the nginx configuration, which did not help.
I also tried different jdks/jres, does not change anything.

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure about this, but I'd recommend to add keep-alive header to your initial request. And to check how it goes with it. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)

Comment: Should have nothing to do with it. the keep-alive connection and its header is for using one single tcp connection to make multiple requestst instead of opening a new connection all the time.